# WPF AutoCompleteBox popup height

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

I'm trying to figure out how to increase the popup height of WPF Toolkit's AutoCompleteBox. Right now, only few items fit in the popup. How do I make it taller? I see there is a MaxPopupHeight property. What about min height?

Comment: I guess you should edit a `Popup` style inside a template of `AutoCompleteBox`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but a thing I've found useful is to specify an explicit height for the popup:

```
<tk:AutoCompleteBox ...>
  <tk:AutoCompleteBox.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
     </Style>
  </tk:AutoCompleteBox.Resources>
</tk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

This also helps with the problem of Toolkit's AutoCompleteBox ignoring MaxDropDownHeight as [several people have encountered](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/b32a9cec-accc-472b-8fcc-1eac77aa3280/).
Actually now I see that it's pretty much an elaboration on a solution proposed by Zabavsky.